# Prevent completion of an order in a callback

Tags: symfony, sylius

Sylius uses **[WinzouStateMachine](https://github.com/winzou/StateMachineBundle)** for state transitions.

Before an order is completed, I have a "before" callback defined like this :

```
sylius_order:
    callbacks:
        before:
            sylius_complete_order:
                on: ["create"]
                do: ["@my_bundle.cart_callback", "processComplete"]
                args: ["object"]
```

This callback checks some stuff and I would like to be able to prevent the completion in this callback in some cases (say, a product is not available anymore), and have the order return to the `cart` state (*and not proceed to the payment, as it would do normally*).

Apparently, returning `false` should do the trick (according to the docs at https://github.com/winzou/state-machine#callbacks) when the callback is defined as `guard` but it needs a "guard" functionality and it's not merged yet, so it doesn't work ;(

Is this still possible with another solution, maybe on the Sylius side, and not with the Winzou default behavior? Is there something like `$event->stopPropagation();` but in the callback, for the order ?
Thanks !

Comment: You could always throw an exception, although not ideal.

Comment: Yes that's what I thought but I think it will be caught earlier than I can process it, so it will 500 for the user, which is not really what I'm looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the actual code there are dispatcher events that you could listen to and then reject the event, which would stop the transition from happening.

In the current code (0.2.3) there are 2 calls that you could listen to (one in the `can` method and the other in the `apply` method).

The [`can` method](https://github.com/winzou/state-machine/blob/0.2.3/src/SM/StateMachine/StateMachine.php#L83-L109)..

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function can($transition)
{
    //...

    if (null !== $this->dispatcher) {
        $event = new TransitionEvent($transition, $this->getState(), $this->config['transitions'][$transition], $this);
        $this->dispatcher->dispatch(SMEvents::TEST_TRANSITION, $event);

        return !$event->isRejected();
    }

    return true;
}
```

The [`apply` method](https://github.com/winzou/state-machine/blob/0.2.3/src/SM/StateMachine/StateMachine.php#L111-L151)..

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function apply($transition, $soft = false)
{
    //...

    $event = new TransitionEvent($transition, $this->getState(), $this->config['transitions'][$transition], $this);

    if (null !== $this->dispatcher) {
        $this->dispatcher->dispatch(SMEvents::PRE_TRANSITION, $event);

        if ($event->isRejected()) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    //...
}
```

Using these event calls you could listen to `SMEvents::TEST_TRANSITION` & `SMEvents::PRE_TRANSITION`, work out whether to transition or not and then reject the event if necessary with `$event->setRejected(true);`. The `TEST_TRANSITION` check has been there for ages but the `PRE_TRANSITION` seems to have been introduced in 0.2.

As the StateMachine object is passed into the event you can use that to get your original model (your Order) like..

```
$order = $event->getStateMachine()->getObject();
```

Comment: Oh, nice, hadn't thought of that. Will try asap. Thanks !

Comment: You can get the object from the statemachine in the event. I've updated my answer.